# Plotting a function using Python where the x and y values are represented in terms of variables

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have a function of the form  `y = a*cos(2*pi*xc)`

Now I would like to plot this from `0` to `10c` and get the output in terms of `a`. This means I would not like to give a specific value to `a,b,c` rather let the function plot be in terms of `a,b,c`.

To give you an idea..say,

```
x = [0, c/4, c/2, 3c/4....10c]
```

correspondingly

```
y = [a, 0, -a, 0, ....a]
```

So the plot will have the x-axis in terms of multiples of `c` and y -axis will be in multiples of `a`

Is there a name for plotting in terms of variables like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly.

The plot contents are always numeric.

But you can multiply `x` by `c`, divide `y` by `a` (so that your function becomes `cos(2*pi*x)`), and change the [xticks](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) and [yticks](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yticks.html) labels:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def xtick(x):
    if x == 0: return 0
    if x == int(x): return '%dc' % x
    return ''

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.25)
y = np.cos(2*np.pi*x)
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
plt.xticks(x, map(xtick, x))
plt.yticks([-1, 0, 1], ['-a', '0', 'a'])
plt.show()
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hallo!! Thanks for the reply..yes this does work..was not aware of xticks and yticks.. Thanks a lot for your help!!